# What is the difference between: Everyone has come VS Everyone has arrived?

Tags: word-usage

What is difference between: "Everyone has come" VS "Everyone has arrived"?

E.g.: A and other people are waiting for B. And A is making a phone call to B:

> Everyone has (come/arrived), where are you now?

Is it possible to use 'come'?

According to the dictionary 'arrive' is more occurate here:

*Come - move or travel towards or into a place thought of as near or familiar to the speaker.*

*Arrive - reach a place at the end of a journey or a stage in a journey.*

because meaning of 'arrive' contains act of reaching the place. But if I use present perfect with 'come', I guess it also means that everyone is already at the place, isn't it?

Comment: The term "arrived" is correct in the sentence "Everyone (else) has arrived; where are you?".  It would not be correct to use "come".  The explanation by @Tᴚoɯɐuo is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, enlisting the verb **come** in a perfect construction gives the sense "traveled to and reached this place". The 'relevance to the present' is locative in nature.

> People had come from miles around to see the strange sight.
>
> We've come to say goodbye.

The focus of **arrived** is not on the travel or the going but on reaching the destination, broadly construed.

> They arrived in Tucson at sunset.
>
> The arrived at an agreement.

Answer (score 0):

- arrive implies reaching a place, often involving time and place.

**Everyone arrived on time for the dinner.**

- **come** (go) implies attend an event.

I invited loads of people but not many came to the dinner.

In a phone call, saying "Where are you now"? It would be more usual to say: Everyone has arrived.